# Exclude results from xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, syntax

This code comes from an supplementary xsl I was sent, when I told my client that the config file is wrongly excluding things with "Northern Ireland" in the title. Now, he's brought it ALL back in, but I need to exclude some of the results  - an example shown below.

The identifying info of the object I would like to filter out of results is **nisr** inside **affectingURI** e.g.key-33793274a92a1f194b3ebcfccfc08927 in the xml posted at the end.

How can I get rid of these 'nisr' results?

```
<xsl:template match="atom:feed" mode="results">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="atom:entry/ukm:Effect"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="ukm:Effect">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@Type= 'Commencement Order' and @AffectedProvisions='specified amended provision(s)'"/>
        <xsl:when test="contains(ukm:AffectingTitle[1], 'Northern Ireland')"/>
        <xsl:when test="contains(ukm:AffectingTitle[1], 'Northern-Ireland')"/>
        <xsl:when test="contains(ukm:AffectedTitle[1], 'Northern Ireland')"/>
        <xsl:when test="contains(ukm:AffectedTitle[1], 'Northern-Ireland')"/>
        <xsl:when test="@Type= 'coming into force'"/>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <tr xsl:exclude-result-prefixes="atom xs xhtml tso db sls ukm">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="resultsAffectedYearNumber"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="resultsAffectedTitle"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="resultsChangedProvision"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="resultsAffectingTitle"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="resultsInForceDates"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="resultsEffectId"/>
            </tr>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```

Here's the source.

-I'd hope to have nothing about "key-33793274a92a1f194b3ebcfccfc08927" in my results, because it contains NISR.

-If you can help me exclude NISR, I'll take the same logic and apply it to "key-e789d8aa9e46169ba1f49655051c66d1" because NIA also in affectingURI is one of six handles I need to omit

-The UK pga (UK public and general act, for those who like to know what they're looking at!) result ("key-fce2f92caeab329b0d33dfb1adca9bdf") will be included. My starting point before the replace config was that this was missing, because it had Northern Ireland in the title, and somewhere that I can't identify, this has been wrongly excluded. The author should have only excluded NIA, NISR, NISI.

```
<entry>
                            <id>http://www.legislation.gov.uk/changes/affected/ukpga/1972/18/affecting/nisr/2016/387/modified/2017-01-19T15:31:27Z</id>
                            <title>The Justice (2015 Act) (Commencement No. 7 and Saving Provisions) Order (Northern Ireland) 2016 effect on Maintenance Orders (Reciprocal Enforcement) Act 1972</title>
                            <updated>2017-01-19T15:31:27Z</updated>
                            <author><name/></author>
                            <ukm:Effect EffectId="key-33793274a92a1f194b3ebcfccfc08927" AffectedClass="UnitedKingdomPublicGeneralAct" AffectedURI="http://www.legislation.gov.uk/id/ukpga/1972/18" AffectingURI="http://www.legislation.gov.uk/id/nisr/2016/387" AffectingClass="NorthernIrelandStatutoryRule" URI="http://www.legislation.gov.uk/id/effect/key-33793274a92a1f194b3ebcfccfc08927" Row="70" Type="Commencement Order" Applied="false" RequiresApplied="true" AffectedProvisions="specified amended provision(s)" Notes="commencement order for 2015 c. 9 (N.I.)" AffectingYear="2016" AffectingNumber="387" AffectingProvisions="art. 2" AffectedYear="1972" AffectedNumber="18" Modified="2017-01-19T15:31:27Z"><ukm:AffectedTitle>Maintenance Orders (Reciprocal Enforcement) Act 1972</ukm:AffectedTitle><ukm:AffectedProvisions>specified amended provision(s)</ukm:AffectedProvisions><ukm:AffectingTitle>The Justice (2015 Act) (Commencement No. 7 and Saving Provisions) Order (Northern Ireland) 2016</ukm:AffectingTitle><ukm:AffectingProvisions><ukm:Section Ref="article-2" URI="http://www.legislation.gov.uk/id/nisr/2016/387/article/2">art. 2</ukm:Section></ukm:AffectingProvisions><ukm:Commenced>commencement order for <ukm:Citation Class="NorthernIrelandAct" URI="http://www.legislation.gov.uk/id/nia/2015/9" Year="2015" Number="9" Title="Justice Act (Northern Ireland) 2015">2015 c. 9 (N.I.)</ukm:Citation></ukm:Commenced><ukm:InForceDates><ukm:InForce Applied="false" Prospective="true" Qualification=""/></ukm:InForceDates></ukm:Effect>
                        </entry><entry>
                            <id>http://www.legislation.gov.uk/changes/affected/ukpga/1973/36/affecting/nia/2016/4/modified/2016-03-25T09:47:14Z</id>
                            <title>Public Services Ombudsman Act (Northern Ireland) 2016 effect on Northern Ireland Constitution Act 1973</title>
                            <updated>2016-03-25T09:47:14Z</updated>
                            <author><name/></author>
                            <ukm:Effect EffectId="key-e789d8aa9e46169ba1f49655051c66d1" AffectedURI="http://www.legislation.gov.uk/id/ukpga/1973/36" AffectedClass="UnitedKingdomPublicGeneralAct" AffectingURI="http://www.legislation.gov.uk/id/nia/2016/4" AffectingClass="NorthernIrelandAct" URI="http://www.legislation.gov.uk/id/effect/nia-2016-4-4ds9a6o2-90" Row="90" Type="repealed" Applied="false" RequiresApplied="true" AffectedProvisions="s. 36(1)(a)(b)" AffectingEffectsExtent="NI" AffectingYear="2016" AffectingNumber="4" AffectingProvisions="Sch. 9" AffectedYear="1973" AffectedNumber="36" Created="2016-03-25T09:47:14Z" Modified="2016-03-25T09:47:14Z"><ukm:AffectedTitle>Northern Ireland Constitution Act 1973</ukm:AffectedTitle><ukm:AffectedProvisions><ukm:Section Ref="section-36-1-a" URI="http://www.legislation.gov.uk/id/ukpga/1973/36/section/36/1/a">s. 36(1)(a)</ukm:Section><ukm:Section Ref="section-36-1-b" URI="http://www.legislation.gov.uk/id/ukpga/1973/36/section/36/1/b">(b)</ukm:Section></ukm:AffectedProvisions><ukm:AffectingTitle>Public Services Ombudsman Act (Northern Ireland) 2016</ukm:AffectingTitle><ukm:AffectingTitle>Public Services Ombudsman Act (Northern Ireland) 2016</ukm:AffectingTitle><ukm:AffectingProvisions><ukm:Section Ref="schedule-9" URI="http://www.legislation.gov.uk/id/nia/2016/4/schedule/9">Sch. 9</ukm:Section></ukm:AffectingProvisions><ukm:CommencementAuthority><ukm:Section Ref="section-64" URI="http://www.legislation.gov.uk/id/nia/2016/4/section/64">s. 64</ukm:Section></ukm:CommencementAuthority><ukm:InForceDates><ukm:InForce Applied="false" Date="2016-04-01" Qualification="wholly in force"/></ukm:InForceDates></ukm:Effect>
                        </entry><entry>
                            <id>http://www.legislation.gov.uk/changes/affected/ukpga/1974/37/affecting/ukpga/2016/25/modified/2017-04-10T10:13:36Z</id>
                            <title>Investigatory Powers Act 2016 effect on Health and Safety at Work etc. Act 1974</title>
                            <updated>2017-04-10T10:13:36Z</updated>
                            <author><name/></author>
                            <ukm:Effect EffectId="key-fce2f92caeab329b0d33dfb1adca9bdf" AffectedClass="UnitedKingdomPublicGeneralAct" AffectedURI="http://www.legislation.gov.uk/id/ukpga/1974/37" AffectingURI="http://www.legislation.gov.uk/id/ukpga/2016/25" AffectingClass="UnitedKingdomPublicGeneralAct" URI="http://www.legislation.gov.uk/id/effect/key-fce2f92caeab329b0d33dfb1adca9bdf" Row="10" Type="inserted" Applied="false" RequiresApplied="true" AffectedProvisions="s. 20(9)(10)" AffectingEffectsExtent="E+W+S+N.I." AffectingYear="2016" AffectingNumber="25" AffectingProvisions="Sch. 2 para. 1" AffectedYear="1974" AffectedNumber="37" Modified="2017-04-10T10:13:36Z"><ukm:AffectedTitle>Health and Safety at Work etc. Act 1974</ukm:AffectedTitle><ukm:AffectedProvisions><ukm:Section Ref="section-20-9" URI="http://www.legislation.gov.uk/id/ukpga/1974/37/section/20/9" FoundRef="section-20">s. 20(9)</ukm:Section><ukm:Section Ref="section-20-10" URI="http://www.legislation.gov.uk/id/ukpga/1974/37/section/20/10" FoundRef="section-20">(10)</ukm:Section></ukm:AffectedProvisions><ukm:AffectingTitle>Investigatory Powers Act 2016</ukm:AffectingTitle><ukm:AffectingTitle>Further Education) Order (Northern Ireland) 2016</ukm:AffectingTitle><ukm:AffectingProvisions><ukm:Section Ref="schedule-2" URI="http://www.legislation.gov.uk/id/ukpga/2016/25/schedule/2">Sch. 2 </ukm:Section><ukm:Section Ref="schedule-2-paragraph-1" URI="http://www.legislation.gov.uk/id/ukpga/2016/25/schedule/2/paragraph/1">para. 1</ukm:Section></ukm:AffectingProvisions><ukm:Savings><ukm:Section Ref="schedule-9" URI="http://www.legislation.gov.uk/id/ukpga/2016/25/schedule/9">Sch. 9 </ukm:Section><ukm:Section Ref="schedule-9-paragraph-7" URI="http://www.legislation.gov.uk/id/ukpga/2016/25/schedule/9/paragraph/7">paras. 7</ukm:Section> <ukm:Section Ref="schedule-9-paragraph-8" URI="http://www.legislation.gov.uk/id/ukpga/2016/25/schedule/9/paragraph/8">8</ukm:Section> <ukm:Section Ref="schedule-9-paragraph-10" URI="http://www.legislation.gov.uk/id/ukpga/2016/25/schedule/9/paragraph/10">10</ukm:Section></ukm:Savings><ukm:CommencementAuthority><ukm:Section Ref="section-272-1" URI="http://www.legislation.gov.uk/id/ukpga/2016/25/section/272/1">s. 272(1)</ukm:Section></ukm:CommencementAuthority><ukm:InForceDates><ukm:InForce Applied="false" Prospective="true" Qualification=""/></ukm:InForceDates></ukm:Effect>
                        </entry>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post a reproducible example, including input and expected output - see: [mcve].

Comment: I will remove this question and post entire section of code. thank you.

Comment: oh, not allowed to post for another half an hour...

Comment: You can edit your question, can you not?

Comment: ah, I saw someone getting slap on the wrist for that... I'll do it now. Thank you @michael.hor257k

Comment: @michael.hor257k did i do a better job posting this query 2nd time around? i have a fair number of views, but no resolution... am I missing something?

Comment: You should really include a sample of the input XML in the question. Should the external link be changed, it would make this question hard to answer. (And some potential answerers may not want to click any external link). You should really include your expected output, so it is clear what you actually expect too. Additionally, you have included a "config" file, but XSLT itself does not need external config files, so it is not clear whether this is relevant to the question. Thank you!

Comment: One thing to note, in your XSLT snippet, the template matching `atom:feed` has a "mode", but you would need an `xsl:apply-templates` using that mode for this template to be matched, but no such statement appears in your XSLT sample. Showing a fuller sample of your XSLT would also help. Thank you.

Comment: thank YOU @TimC. The link is the input XML - I note your concerns about clicking this, but it's UK government so it is safe to click (and won't change). Output comes as a word doc, so I can't see how to post xml for that - it's just about skipping some results (both results in the link given would be skipped so maybe it's not the best example). I'll edit the question, replace link with XML. remove config. I can't see "mode" anywhere else apart from in this file. (I don't know how to open dll - would it be there?). One last edit, then I think I'll give up and weed out by hand :(

Comment: reposted @TimC - is it looking better? sorry about mode - I can only think it's referring to the "mode" in otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I fully understand the question, but when you say "I would like to filter out of results is nisr inside affectingURI" then one approach to solving this problem is by making use of template matching to exclude things.

You currently have a template matching `ukm:Effect` which matches all such named elements

```
<xsl:template match="ukm:Effect">
```

If you have a rule the `ukm:Effect` elements are to be excluded where nisr is inside affectingURI, you you should add another template like so

```
<xsl:template match="ukm:Effect[contains(@AffectingURI, '/nisr/')]" />
```

Because this template has a condition after then element name, it will have a higher priority that the other template, resulting in that `ukm:Effect` element being excluded.

So, instead of having an `xsl:choose` / `xsl:when` to exclude elements...

```
<xsl:when test="contains(ukm:AffectingTitle[1], 'Northern Ireland')"/>
```

You could rewrite this as a template match to exclude it

```
<xsl:template match="ukm:Effect[contains(ukm:AffectingTitle[1], 'Northern Ireland')]"/>
```

Be wary though, a template matching `ukm:Effect[contains(ukm:AffectingTitle[1], 'Northern Ireland')]` would have the same priority as a template matching `ukm:Effect[contains(@AffectingURI, '/nisr')]` (as both have conditions). It is considered an error if two templates can match the same element with the same priority. You might need to stick a `priority` attribute on the second template in this case

```
<xsl:template match="ukm:Effect[contains(@AffectingURI, '/nisr')]" priority="2" />
```

Alternatively, you can one template, with a big conditional check

```
<xsl:template match="ukm:Effect[contains(@AffectingURI, '/nisr/') or contains(ukm:AffectingTitle[1], 'Northern Ireland')]"/>
```

Comment: all really helpful, thank you. I'll have a bash - the whole thing takes nearly an hour to run, so I will go quiet while I play around. The only thing I'm not sure about is I am hoping to exclude nisr. I don't see any "not(contains " or ! so I think maybe I've confused you with the question. I think your helpful suggestion asks xsl to INclude nisr, doesn't it? any tips on how to EXclude it? thanks again

Comment: When `@AffectingURI`contains `/nisr/` then template `<xsl:template match="ukm:Effect[contains(@AffectingURI, '/nisr/')]" />` will be used. If you see, this is self-closed, and so will do nothing. This has the affect of ignore that element, thus excluding it from the output.

Comment: thanks so much for your help with this. I'm afraid that although your comments make sense, and have increased my knowledge, my problem is not resolved, so I'm off back to the client, and will wait for them to rectify what is - after all  - their mistake. thanks again.